# how to find a side total length

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I have this simple setup:

[image]

I'd like to walk this perimeter and find the total length of every side, so as to find which side is longer:

[image]

How can I do that with a python script? Thank you
EDIT: added a clearer picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Co linear Edges**

below is a script that returns all co linear edges from a set of input edges. Two edges are colinear if they share a vertex and the edge vectors are parallel (dot product of normalized vectors is one)

The method `edge_line_segments(...)` takes as its arguments, the bmesh, a list of edges from that bmesh and a tolerance angle for how far from parallel the edges can be.

The return dictionary has a key "segments" which is a list of edges in each line segment.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import sin, radians

def tag(iterable, value):
    for x in iterable:
        x.tag = value    

def vec(e):
    v0, v1 = e.verts
    return (v1.co - v0.co).normalized()

def parallel(e1, e2, tol_angle=0):
    return abs(vec(e1).dot(vec(e2)) - 1) <= sin(tol_angle)

def line_select_extend(edge, v, tol_angle=0):  
    edges = []
    while v:
        segments = [e for e in v.link_edges
                if not e is edge
                and e.tag
                and parallel(e, edge, tol_angle)]
        if segments:
            edge = segments[0]
            edges.extend(segments)
            v = edge.other_vert(v)
        else:
            v = None  
    return edges     

def select_segment(edge, tol_angle=0):
    v0, v1 = edge.verts
    edges = line_select_extend(edge, v0, tol_angle)
    edges.reverse()
    edges.append(edge)
    edges.extend(line_select_extend(edge, v1, tol_angle))
    return edges

def edge_line_segments(bm, edges=[], tol_angle=0):
    ret = {"segments" : []}
    tag(bm.edges, False)
    tag(edges, True)
    edges = set(edges)
    while edges:
        segments = select_segment(next(iter(edges)))
        ret["segments"].append(segments)
        edges -= set(segments)
    tag(bm.edges, False)
    return ret
```

**To use.**

Test script below to run in edit mode.  Calls method with  boundary (perimeter edges), sorts the segments by length, selects the edges of the longest segment and writes a report to system console.

```
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)    
perimeter = [e for e in bm.edges if e.is_boundary]  
ret = edge_line_segments(bm, edges=perimeter, tol_angle=radians(5))
segments = [(sum(e.calc_length() for e in s), s)
        for s in ret["segments"]]
segments.sort(key=lambda s: s[0])

for i, (length, edges) in enumerate(segments):
    print("linked segment %d edges length %.3f" % (len(edges), length))

    for e in edges:
        e.select = i == len(segments) - 1 
        print("\t edge %d len %.2f" % (e.index, e.calc_length()))
```

Comment: This puts me on the right way, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the following script you're able to find the indexnumber of the corner vertices. Just put the object in editmode and select all corner vertices. The script will print a list for the second script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object

mesh = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
vertices = bm.faces[0].verts

corner_verts =[]
for v in vertices:
    if v.select:
        corner_verts.append(v.index)

print(corner_verts)

bm.free()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Replace the corner_verts array with the output from the first script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object

mesh = obj.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

corner_verts = [3, 11, 10, 1, 6, 5, 0, 15, 14, 2, 13, 12]
len_corner_verts = len(corner_verts)

for i in range(0, len_corner_verts):
    v1 = bm.verts[corner_verts[i % len_corner_verts]].co
    v2 = bm.verts[corner_verts[(i + 1) % len_corner_verts]].co
    dv = v2 -v1  
    print('from {0} to {1}, length: {2}'.format(v1, v2, dv.length))

print('---')

bm.free()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```