# Select outer edges with Python BMesh

Tags: python

I have a Python script in which I get the BMesh from an existing mesh. Then I want to get the outer edges of the mesh, not the inner edges, mesh could for instance look like this:

[image]

I want to get the edges as a sequence that are not in the inside.

Thx for your help.

Edit: Can get the outer edges now like that:

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

outer_edges = [edge for edge in bm.edges if edge.is_boundary]

for edge in outer_edges:
    vertices.append(edge.verts[0])
```

The only problem I have now is that I want to order them clockwise, any idea for this?

Edit 06.11.2020: Ok ended up with this one here:

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

vert = bm.verts[0]
prev = None

for i in range(len(bm.verts)):
    next = None
    for v in [e.other_vert(vert) for e in vert.link_edges if e.is_boundary]:
        if (v != prev):
            next = v

    vertices.append(obj.matrix_world @ vert.co)

    if next == None:
        break
    
    prev, vert = vert, next
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47192/select-mesh-perimeter

Comment: @batFINGER Oh, that simple:-) Thx

Comment: NP, Also Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108830/how-to-find-a-side-total-length

Comment: @batFINGER Works to get the outer edges, now I need to reorder them clockwise, any idea? Edited the question.

Comment: Baulked on closing in first place re this. Search is down for maintenance atm have used this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110996/15543 to get edge loops, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197371/15543   could use similar for edge ring.  If you get one edge, its verts are wound counter clockwise to face normal. Use to get initial direction then walk `edge.other_vert(v).linik_edges` until back to start.  Sure have answered this before too. (posted other link as it walks corner to corner)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area   could also use https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186067/what-is-the-bmesh-equivalent-to-bpy-ops-mesh-shortest-path-select/186137 (narrowing down selection to boundary edges)

Comment: @batFINGER : Ok, thx worked with walking over link_edges, my algo is in the description, thx!